# Oracle how to give permission to an user on a different schema

Tags: oracle, sql-grant

I have an Oracle user user1 and a schema schema1. I want to give permissions insert, update and delete to this user on this schema.

I only find in the documentation that I can give permissions on this schema tables.

Is there a way to give permission on whole schema?

Answer (score 0):

You can add roles and privileges to the user or use the grant command.

https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefsqljgrant.html

You can also use the `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES TO {USERNAME}` command.